# Windows 2008 R2 folder prompt for credentials

Tags: permissions, directory, credentials

I cannot find an answer to this question, so I am hoping someone here can help.

We have a couple folders on our NAS that only our Help Desk techs can get into for install and troubleshooting purposes.

We are looking for a way to allow the Help Desk Techs to open those folders while logged in as a regular user without having to map the drive.

Basically they browse to the NAS find the folder in the list and when they click to open it get prompted for their credentials.

Is there any way to do this in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 0):

If the regular user already has open connections to other shares on this NAS, it's not possible. You cannot have a single login session connect to an SMB server with multiple credentials.

You could solve this other ways.

1. Serve the directory up via a different protocol from SMB, like HTTP or FTP or NFS.
2. Put the share on a different server just for IT.
3. Give the techs a USB key with the files they need.
4. I haven't tested this, but on the user's workstation, the tech might be able to open a CMD window using "runas" and their credentials, and access the share via UNC from that CMD window. Worth trying.